# how to use index to call other dataframe data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

[image]

I have created a following dataframe and would like to use the index stock code to call other data and add a new column and 'price'

```
        RSI
Stock   
HOYA    61.940859
HKSE    61.657187
BABA    54.881989
HSI 53.664616
Galaxy  52.561760
```

and another dataframe that have the latest closing price of twenty stocks call 'Close'

How do I add a column to my first dataframe? 
when my input

```
df['Stock'] 
#this return an error ??
```

And Also how do I add a new column to df with the latest closing price (ignoring the NaN)?? Please see the attached screen shot on my other dataframe. 
thanks I am new to python and trying to apply it to my day to day work.

[image]

Comment: missing attachment. And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, the name of your first DataFrame is TOP so use TOP['Price'] to add a new column named 'Price'.

To have the latest closing price of HSI:
p_of_hsi = close.iloc[-2][1]

## -2 for the second last row and 1 for first column

Now assign this value of HSI in TOP DataFrame
TOP['Price'][3] = p_of_hsi

Comment: thank you!! sorry for the confusion I have try to make the question clearer below